# Servicestack redirect to metadata

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, servicestack

i've the following problem: i've a web service application that uses ServiceStack. I'd like to register as base path "/api", but even if I set DefaultRedirectPath to "/api/metadata", when i start the app it won't redirect automatically (if i type "/api/metadata" all works)
Can anyone help me? 
Here's my code inside AppHost

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
     SetConfig(new HostConfig
     {
         DefaultRedirectPath = "/api/metadata"
     });
}



public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup()
    {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
          .Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost
        {
            PathBase = "/api",
            AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: What version of .NET Core + ServiceStack are you using?

Comment: @mythz Net Core 3.1 with ServiceStack 6.0.2.. I've also downgrade to version 5.14.0 but nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'd consider not using an `/api` PathBase which would [disable the new /api route](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v6#new-api-route). E.g. if you didn't have a `/api` PathBase you would automatically be able to call a Hello API from `/api/Hello`.

But if you you still want to host ServiceStack at a custom `/api` path know that this is the path that ServiceStack will be mounted at, i.e. from where ServiceStack will be able to receive any requests.

Which also means you should just use `/metadata` which will redirect from where ServiceStack is mounted at, so if you had:

```cs
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("MyApp", typeof(MyServices).Assembly) {}

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        SetConfig(new HostConfig {
            DefaultRedirectPath = "/metadata"
        });
    }
}
```

Then calling `https://localhost:5001/api` will redirect to `https://localhost:5001/api/metadata`.

ServiceStack can only see requests from `/api` where it's mounted at, so if you wanted to redirect the `/` route to the metadata page you would need to register a custom ASP.NET Core handler to do it, e.g:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost {
        PathBase = "/api",
    });

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapGet("/", async context => 
            context.Response.Redirect("/api/metadata"));
    });
}
```

> Note: you no longer need to set `NetCoreAppSettings()` which is populated by default

Comment: sorry @mythz, one thing: this works if I host the app in an own site (I use iis). If I host the app under Default web site, I have to specify in the redirect path also the application folder, right? At the moment if I type http://localhost/myapp/api it redirects to http://localhost/api/metadata
I think the best thing is to dedicate a site for each app, but in our development server is not handy

Comment: @paolot Things you can look is explicitly setting a `Config.WebHostUrl`, e.g. you could populate from appsettings or you could override `GetBaseUrl()` in your AppHost to control what BaseUrl should be used per request.